# MySQL statement to read data from one table with checks on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

**Achievement**:

[image: Achievement]

**Achieves**:

[image: Achieves]

**Question**:

I want to retrieve rows from table Achievement. But, I do not want all the rows, I want the rows that a specific Steam ID has acquired. Let's take STEAM_0:0:46481449 for example, I want to check first the list of IDs that STEAM_0:0:46481449 has acquired (4th column in Achieves table states whether achievement is acquired or not) and then read only those achievements.

I hope that made sense, if not let me know so I can explain a little better.

I know how to do this with two MySQL statements, but can this be done with a single MySQL statement? That would be awesome if so please tell me :D

EDIT: I will add the two queries below

```
SELECT * FROM Achieves WHERE Achieves.SteamID = 'STEAM_0:0:46481449' AND Achieves.Acquired = 1;
```

Then after that I do the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Achievement;
```

And then through PHP I would check the IDs that I should take and output those. That's why I wanted to get the same result in 1 query since it's more readable and easier.

Comment: Add the two statements you are use

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You need to use a join

Comment: I added the two statements in the OP

Comment: Where do you refer to `Achivement` ID in `achives` table?

Comment: The second column in Achieves that read ID is a secondary key to referes to Achievement ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql *left join*, applying conditions on second table will filter the result when join conditions doesn't matter:

```
   Select * from achievement 
   left join achieves on (achievement.id=achieves.id) 
   where achieves.acquired=1 and achieves.SteamID = 'STEAM_0:0:46481449'
```

Besides,I suggest not using ID in the achieves table as the shared key between two tables. Name it something else.

Comment: Thank you, this worked indeed. By the way, I know my namings are messed up but I am used to it like this. I always use Achievement.ID instead of just Id so I have no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a left join makes sense here.  There is no case where you don't want to see the Achievement table.

Something like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Achieves A
 JOIN Achievement B on A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE A.SteamID = 'STEAM_0:0:46481449' 
   AND A.Acquired = 1;
```

Comment: I have tried your query on the database. It worked. Both outputs the same result. Thank you either way.